# select query which matches name in input query

Tags: mysql

```
**id    eid name    value**
8   1   bbbb        3433
7   1   abce        1234
6   1   abcd        efgh
```

Need to select value which has name = bbbb and abce.
I tried below query:

```
select * from emp where name in("bbbb","abce");
```

I am getting result as expected.
But if my query is below:

```
select * from emp where name in("bbbb","abce","abc");
```

my expected output is empty result because there is no name matches as abc in my above table.
But i am getting result which matches bbbb and abce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you do is simply select rows with a filter that uses the IN operator, but you requirement is different.
First get the `eid`s that contain all the names in the list and then filter:

```
select * from emp
where name in('bbbb', 'abce', 'abc')
and eid in (
  select eid from emp 
  where name in('bbbb', 'abce', 'abc')
  group by eid
  having count(distinct name) = 3
);
```

Check the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=169e70abb6743fc8eef9bce0f0184d72).

Answer (score 0):

A query:

```
select * from emp where name in("bbbb","abce","abc");
```

means that find emp's where name is any of those listed: bbbb or abce or abc

If you want to find emp's where each name listed appears at least once

```
select * 
from emp 
where name in("bbbb","abce","abc") and 3 = (
  select count(distinct name) 
  from emp 
  where name in("bbbb","abce","abc")
)
```

Answer (score -1):

IF you expect no result means you need to use AND condition :

```
select * from emp where name = "bbbb" and name="abce" and name = "abc";
```